# Why is Ubuntu searching for (pritnter) drivers when there is a working driver? (turbodriver)

Tags: drivers, printing

I have installed a turbodriver for a Canon iX4000 (A3) printer. Each time I print something, Ubuntu starts searching for a (Gutenprint) printer driver. Why? Can I stop this?

suggestions?
TIA

Comment: A good suggestion is any question needs to have the Ubuntu version number in it.

Comment: Right: Ubuntu 20.04.1